# Ujevic method in C- root is returning -nan

Tags: c, methods, nan, numeric

I have been trying to code the ujevic method for solving non linear equations. but upon compiling the code with given data, it return the root as - nan. The actual root should be 1 and no. of iterations 75.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

#define f(x) ((x*x*x)-(3*x)+2)
#define g(x) ((3*x*x)-3)

void main() {
    float a, b, x0, xk, z0, xt, y;
    int i = 0;
    printf("\nEnter The Value Of a: ");
    scanf("%f", &a);
    printf("\nEnter The Value Of b: ");
    scanf("%f", &b);
    printf("\nEnter The Value Of x0: ");
    scanf("%f", &x0);
    printf("\nEnter The Value Of Alpha: ");
    scanf("%f", &y);
    do {
        xt = x0;
        z0 = x0 - y * (f(x0) / g(x0));
        xk = x0 + 4 * (z0 - x0) * (f(x0) / ((3 * f(x0)) - (2 * f(z0))));
        x0 = xk;
        i++;
    } while (fabs(xk - xt >= 0.000000000000000001));
    printf("The value of root is: %f", xk);
    printf("\n the no of iterations is %d", i);
}
```

Output:

```
Enter The Value Of a: 0.5
Enter The Value Of b: 1.2
Enter The Value Of x0: 0.5
Enter The Value Of Alpha: 0.1
The value of root is: -nan
the no of iterations is 43
```

Comment: 0) `float` ==> `double` and other required changes in scanf 1) wrong parenthesis placement in `fabs(xk-xt>=0.000000000000000001)`

Comment: It's odd that you input `a` and `b`, but do not use them.

Comment: Generally speaking, the only arithmetic operation that produces a NaN from non-NaN operands is floating-point division of 0 by 0.  That can happen in your program if the root estimate happens to land exactly on the true root before the loop termination condition is satisfied.  Using `double` instead of `float` would make that considerably less likely.

Comment: `fabs(xk-xt>=0.000000000000000001)` yeah right.

Comment: The method assumes that the f'(x) is non-zero, but you have f(1) = f'(1) = 0.

Comment: gcc u.c -lm -Wall -Wextra

Answer (score 0):

When `x0` reaches the value 0.999802410602569580078125, `f(x0)` is calculated as zero. In `f(x0)`, `x0*x0*x0` is calculated as 0.999407351016998291015625, and `3*x0` is 2.999407291412353515625. Subtracting these would give −1.999999940395355224609375 mathematically, but the `float` format in your C implementation (likely IEEE-754 binary32) cannot represent that number. The closest numbers it can represent are −1.99999988079071044921875 and −2. Of those, −2 is closer to −1.999999940395355224609375 than −1.99999988079071044921875 is, so, when `x0*x0*x0 - 3*x0` is calculated using `float` arithmetic, the result is −2. Then adding `2`, the final step in the `f` macro, yields zero.

The calculation of `f(z0)` proceeds similarly, and then `f(x0)/((3*f(x0))-(2*f(z0)))` evaluates as `0 / (0-0)`, which yields a NaN.

You have two mathematical problems in the code, aside from various other issues. One is that your loop approaches a point where `f(x0)/((3*f(x0))-(2*f(z0)))` will be mathematically zero. At some point, the calculations in that loop will fail. I have not looked at the Ujevic method and do not know what the intent is here. At the very least, once `((3*f(x0))-(2*f(z0)))` evaluates as zero, you cannot continue the loop anymore.

Second, `fabs(xk-xt) >=0.000000000000000001)`, which you apparently intended to write instead of `fabs(xk-xt>=0.000000000000000001)` is futile with `float` variables using the common format for `float` whenb `xk` is near 1. In this format, the smallest different between two numbers just under 1 is 0.000000059604644775390625, which is much larger than 0.000000000000000001. It is therefore impossible for `fabs(xk-xt)` to be smaller than 0.000000000000000001 unless it is zero, meaning `xk` and `xt` are equal. Even if the variables used the format commonly used for `double` (IEEE-754 binary64), 0.000000000000000001 is smaller than the smallest difference representable in numbers just under 1. You need a larger bound in this test, or you need to ensure the loop will always converge to identical `xk` and `xt`.

Comment: You might also tell the OP that the macros definitions `f(x)` and `g(x)` are not properly parenthesized, which does not cause bug in this code fragment, but surely will for any non trivial macro argument.

Comment: Technically, `fabs(xk-xt)` can be smaller than `1e-18` if `xk` and `xt` are much smaller than `1.0`. This convergence test is way too simplistic.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems in your code:

- the return type of `main` is `int`, not `void`.
- you should use type `double` instead of `float`: the limited precision of type `float` causes errors with your computation.
- the test `while(fabs(xk - xt >= 0.000000000000000001))` is incorrect. You probably mean:

  ```
    while (fabs(xk - xt) >= 0.000000000000000001)
  ```
- the argument `x` in the expansion of macros `f(x)` and `g(x)` should be parenthesized to avoid operator precedence issues when passing non trivial expressions as macro arguments.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

#define f(x) ((x)*(x)*(x)-3*(x)+2)
#define g(x) (3*(x)*(x)-3)

int main() {
    double a, b, x0, xk, z0, xt, y;
    int i = 0;
    printf("\nEnter The Value Of a: ");
    if (scanf("%lf", &a) != 1)
        return 1;
    printf("\nEnter The Value Of b: ");
    if (scanf("%lf", &b) != 1)
        return 1;
    printf("\nEnter The Value Of x0: ");
    if (scanf("%lf", &x0) != 1)
        return 1;
    printf("\nEnter The Value Of Alpha: ");
    if (scanf("%lf", &y) != 1)
        return 1;
    do {
        xt = x0;
        z0 = x0 - y * (f(x0) / g(x0));
        xk = x0 + 4 * (z0 - x0) * (f(x0) / ((3 * f(x0)) - (2 * f(z0))));
        x0 = xk;
        i++;
    } while (fabs(xk - xt) >= 1.0e-18);
    printf("The value of root is: %f\n", xk);
    printf("the number of iterations is %d\n", i);
    return 0;
}
```

The output is still `nan`:

```
Enter The Value Of a: 0.5
Enter The Value Of b: 1.2
Enter The Value Of x0: 0.5
Enter The Value Of Alpha: 0.1
The value of root is: nan
the number of iterations is 101
```

Using the more precise type `long double`, there are more iterations, but still the same `nan` output:

```
Enter The Value Of a: 0.5
Enter The Value Of b: 1.2
Enter The Value Of x0: 0.5
Enter The Value Of Alpha: 0.1
The value of root is: nan
the number of iterations is 119
```

Your algorithm fails because `(3 * f(x0) - 2 * f(z0))` becomes zero before the `xt` and `xk` get closer than `1.0e-18`.

Adding a sanity test `if (3 * f(x0) - 2 * f(z0) == 0) break;` and initializing `xk = x0;` before the loop gives this output:

```
Enter The Value Of a: 0.5
Enter The Value Of b: 1.2
Enter The Value Of x0: 0.5
Enter The Value Of Alpha: 0.1
The value of root is: 1.000000
the number of iterations is 100
```

Note that the convergence test is incorrect: `fabs(xk - xt) >= 1.0e-18` tests the absolute difference, not the relative difference. You should instead use something like:

```
   while (fabs(xk - xt) / fmax(fabs(xk), fabs(xt)) >= 1.0e-8);
```

Here is an updated version that does converge in fewer than 100 iterations, ie: before the sanity test kicks:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

#define f(x) ((x)*(x)*(x)-3*(x)+2)
#define g(x) (3*(x)*(x)-3)

int main() {
    double a, b, x0, xk, z0, xt, y;
    int i = 0;
    printf("\nEnter The Value Of a: ");
    if (scanf("%lf", &a) != 1)
        return 1;
    printf("\nEnter The Value Of b: ");
    if (scanf("%lf", &b) != 1)
        return 1;
    printf("\nEnter The Value Of x0: ");
    if (scanf("%lf", &x0) != 1)
        return 1;
    printf("\nEnter The Value Of Alpha: ");
    if (scanf("%lf", &y) != 1)
        return 1;
    xk = x0;
    do {
        xt = x0;
        z0 = x0 - y * (f(x0) / g(x0));
        if (3 * f(x0) - 2 * f(z0) == 0)
            break;
        xk = x0 + 4 * (z0 - x0) * (f(x0) / ((3 * f(x0)) - (2 * f(z0))));
        x0 = xk;
        i++;
    } while (fabs(xk - xt) / fmax(fabs(xk), fabs(xt)) >= 1.0e-8);
    printf("The value of root is: %f\n", xk);
    printf("the number of iterations is %d\n", i);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Enter The Value Of a: 0.5
Enter The Value Of b: 1.2
Enter The Value Of x0: 0.5
Enter The Value Of Alpha: 0.1
The value of root is: 1.000000
the number of iterations is 88
```